# Three days before Matan Torah and three days of fast before Purim

Tags: commentaries, purim, shavuos, kabbalat-hatorah

Bnei Yisrael had to prepare themselves for [three](https://www.etzion.org.il/en/when-were-3-days-preparation-matan-torah) days before the giving of the Torah.

As a parallel to this receiving of the Torah, the Jews "accepted" the Torah on Purim ([kiy'mu v'kiblu](https://www.torahweb.org/torah/2012/moadim/rwil_purim.html)). The turning point in the story occurs after Esther and her servants (and all the people) take 3 days to prepare themselves for her meeting with the king.

Are there commentaries which tie the specific events in the timeline of Purim to the timeline of Matan Torah at Har Sinai?

Comment: Related preceding question on what happened on Purim: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103363/matan-oral-torah-on-purim-details

Comment: The three days of fasting were in Nissan, but the miracle salvation was next Adar. That might be why more commentaries don't make the link. Still a great point.

Answer (score 3):

yes

In sefer CHELEK YOFFE (written by the son of reb chaim palagi ) he writes…………that these three days were in mirror of shloshes ymei hagbolo needed before matan torah in sefer shmoiss 19:15

source: the megilla ester by oz vehadar (mesivta)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could perhaps elaborate please...

Comment: @Dov Presumably he means what OP meant in his question.

Comment: @NT I realise that, but he has not said any different to the OP - I would like to hear what he adds....

Comment: I add the commentary who makes the connection and timeline